# How to select Row from mysql database using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services

Hi All,
           Following is my table

```
Table:- Project
         -Project_ID (primary)
         -ProjectName

 Table:- Task
        -Task_ID ( primary)
        -project_ID
        -TaskName
```

I want to select task name from project table.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("select TaskName from Project left join Task on Project.Project_ID = Task.project_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select P.Project_ID, P.ProjectName, T.Task_ID,".
  " T.TaskName from Task T".
  " left outer join Project P on P.Project_ID=T.project_ID");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Project_ID'] . " " . $row['Project_ID'];
  echo $row['ProjectName'] . " " . $row['ProjectName'];
  echo $row['Task_ID'] . " " . $row['Task_ID'];
  echo $row['TaskName '] . " " . $row['TaskName '];
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```